# Conditional Update Statement returning incorrect results on SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to update a table in SQL Server 2012 Management Studio. Rather than writing four separate `Update` statements, I'm attempting to see if it is possible to write one query that will update the same table for one column in four different ways depending on what the value of a column stores.

Assume I have a table called `table_food` with the following structure

```
|Customer|Preference|
+--------+----------+
|John    |McDs      |
|Div     |KFC       |
|Paul    |KFC       |
|Pablo   |Wasabi    |
```

My idea is to update the `Preference` column to new values and the query I had written was:

```
UPDATE table_food
SET Preference = 
    CASE WHEN Preference = 'McDs' Then 'Burger'
         WHEN Preference = 'KFC' Then 'KingsMeal'
    END
```

Now on my actual table, there are only 8 different options selected for preference and I just need two update 4. (I've just done two as an example above but I have four when statements...so just another two lines)

When I run the query it shows far more rows being affected and checking the results after I notice now there's only one option shown "Burger" with a count of 8 and all the other rows have been set to `null`. Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That query will update every row on your table since it lacks a WHERE clause.  And a CASE WHEN expression returns NULL if none of the WHEN conditions are true.  You might want a query like:

```
UPDATE table_food
SET Preference = 
    CASE WHEN Preference = 'McDs' Then 'Burger'
         WHEN Preference = 'KFC' Then 'KingsMeal'
    END
WHERE Preference in ('McDs','KFC')
```

Answer (score 2):

add `else` on your `case` statement.

```
UPDATE table_food
SET Preference = 
    CASE WHEN Preference = 'McDs' Then 'Burger'
         WHEN Preference = 'KFC' Then 'KingsMeal'
    ELSE Preference 
    END
```

or if you only want to update affected rows, you do `update from`

```
UPDATE table_food
SET Preference = t2.newPreference
FROM
    (SELECT CASE WHEN Preference = 'McDs' Then 'Burger'
                WHEN Preference = 'KFC' Then 'KingsMeal'
                WHEN Preference = 'KFC1' Then 'KingsMeal1'
                WHEN Preference = 'KFC'2 Then 'KingsMeal2'
            END as newPreference, Preference
    FROM table_food) t2
WHERE t2.Preference = table_food.Preference and coalesce(t2.newPreference, '') != ''
```